# How to call a functor with template paramerers in c++?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I would like to do something like this in `c++17`:

```cpp
template<class FuncT>
void call_function(FuncT&& f)
{
    f<int>(); // issue
}


template<typename U>
void foo()
{
    U u = 42;
    // ...
}


int main()
{
    call_function(foo);
    
    return 0;
}
```

but `g++` gives `error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’`.

How to specify the type `int` when calling the functor `f` in `call_function`?

Comment: You need to create a function from the template by instantiating `foo`. (And there is no functor in this code.)

Comment: `call_function(foo<int>)`; And `f()` like a normal function.

Comment: `call_function([]<typename T>(){ foo<T>(); })` with `f.template operator<int>()();`?

Answer (score 1):

In your sample, foo is a function. A function is not an objet then cannot be specialized inside `call_function()`.

Functors are objects, and can be specialized.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits> 

 template<typename FuncT>
void  call_function( FuncT&& fctor ) {
    // ugly, but we can retrieve the function operator as template<int>
    std::forward<FuncT>(fctor).template operator()<int>();
}

struct Functor {
     template<typename T>
    void  operator()() {
        std::cout << "functor called for type T=" <<  typeid(T).name();
    }
};

int  main() {
    call_function( Functor{} );
}
```

Comment: `foo` is not a function, its a function template

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no functor in your code. The term "functor" is usually used to denote a type (or instances thereof) with an `operator()`. What you have is a function template. The more general term is callable (basically anything that can be called via usual call syntax like `f()`).

You have to decide whether the function to be called is a runtime parameter or already known at compile time. When it is known at compile time, you can use a template template argument:

```
template<template <class> typename F>
void call_function()
{
    F<int>{}();
}

template <typename T>
struct foo {
    void operator()(){
        std::cout << "hello \n";
    }
};
```

Different instantiations of `call_function` can use functor templates, instantiate it with `int`, create an instance, and call its `operator()`. For example:

```
call_function<foo>();
```

On the other hand, when the function to be instantiated should be chosen at runtime, you can defer the instantiation of the function by wrapping it in a functor with templated `operator()`:

```
template<typename F>
void call_function2(F&& f)
{
    std::forward<F>(f). template operator()<int>();
}


struct bar {
    template <typename T>
    void operator()(){
        std::cout << "world \n";
    }
};
```

Note that `bar` itself is not a template. You can create an instance, pass it to `call_function2` where its `operator()` is instantiated for type `int`:

```
call_function2(bar{});
```

The second approach is more flexible because you can also use it with the above `foo` function template by wrapping that inside a lambda (which has a templated `operator()`):

```
 call_function2([]<typename T>(){ foo<T>{}();});
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/aG3dxer63)